# Header and Div Underneath

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap and am pretty new to coding. I have taught myself from videos and online forums, so my knowledge and understanding is pretty scattered because of everyones "Own Way" of coding.

My question though:

Is it proper to create a Navbar Header and then offset the margin of the next div so that way it will sit underneath the header?

Or,

is there a better and more efficient way of making the div sit underneath the Navbar header without offsetting its margin?

I have looked at so many forums and this topic is all over the place. I figured asking on here would hopefully help my understanding and hopefully others who are wondering this same question.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Look at the `box model`

Comment: If your new to coding scap bootstrap and actually learns CSS Bootstrap is for people who are trying to speed through projects more efficiently to cut time. it will offer very little insight into CSS and what is all actually going on.